# Downloading a file with MVC POST

Tags: mvc

I want to be able to do something like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(object model)
    {
        if (model.OptionType == "Download")
        {
            var fileData = _service.GetPdf();
            if (fileData == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ValidationMessages.Get(ValidationMessages.Codes.SystemError));
                return View(model);
            }
            return File(fileData, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

However sitecore is complaining that OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used. I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740725/sitecore-mvc-outputstream-is-not-available-when-a-custom-textwriter-is-used) but if I do a RedirectToAction then I can't set the error as a ModelState error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Sitecore.

Comment: The above code would work in a non-sitecore environment, hence it has everything to do with sitecore.

Comment: You seem to already have the solution. Why can't you place the RedirectToAction call where you currently return File()?

Comment: Indeed, I've gone with that solution and to help the performance I'm adding the pdf to the session and reading it back again since _service.GetPdf() takes a while to generate the PDF.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because resolved by OP/question no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your filestream in a `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Index(object model)
{
    if (model.OptionType == "Download")
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(PDFSTREAM);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "file.pdf"
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Is IHttpActionResult in System.Web.Http? It's saying HttpRequestBase doesn't contain a definition for CreateResponse.

Comment: Sorry, my answer is based on `ApiController`, I see now that it is not usable in this context.